# Connecting external display turns both screens black

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt-display

I updated from 10.8.1 to 10.8.2 for my MacBook Pro Retina with my external 27" Thunderbolt display. When I connect to my Thunderbolt display both screens are black. I can only see my mouse pointer and sometimes little boxes of display. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The solution explained in [this Apple Discussions thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4318302?start=0&tstart=0) worked for me.

1. Delete `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist`.
2. Delete `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.windowserver.XXXXX.plist`.
3. [Reset NVRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379).